# How do i extract the number of windows open?

Tags: javascript, python, image-processing, monitoring

How do I detect the number of windows open on the screen?
Like for example, if I have chrome, visual studio, notepad open, I need to get the number of windows open as 3.
Is there a way to detect the number of windows open, specifically from a screen share or via javascript as the application is going to be an online exam taking website?

Comment: It is *not* possible to have that sort of control via a website. Even if the students need to install some application, they can find a way around it by reverse engineering it.

Comment: In the online exam, ask questions that are not *googleable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites are highly sandboxed programs. They don't communicate with the OS directly, only through [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API). If the feature you want is not available in the Web APIs, you *cannot* use it.

I don't know every Web API, but i don't think there's any that gives access to the number of open windows. The [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) looks promising, but I found no method that returns the number of open windows.

Also, even if there was, you would be trusting the user that he/she didn't modify your client (your client-side code), and I believe in this case you don't want to trust the user.